# Disabling android's chrome pull-down-to-refresh feature

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, meta-tags

I've created a small HTML5 web application for my company.

This application displays a list of items and everything works fine.

The application is mainly used on android phones and Chrome as browser. Also, the site is saved on the home screen so Android manage the whole thing as an app (<strike>using a WebView I guess</strike>).

Chrome <strike>Beta (and I think also the Android System WebView)</strike> has introduced a "pull down to refresh" feature ([See this link for example](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Chrome-Beta-for-Android-updated-with-a-quite-handy-pull-down-to-refresh-feature_id65360)).

This is an handy feature but I was wondering if it can be disabled with some meta tag (or javascript stuff) because the refresh can be easily triggered by the user while navigating the list and the whole app is reloaded.

Also this is a feature not needed by the application.

<strike>I know that this feature is still available only in Chrome beta, but I have the sensation that this is landing on the stable app, too.</strike>

Thank you!

Edit: I've uninstalled Chrome Beta and the link pinned to the home screen now opens with the stable Chrome. So the pinned links starts with Chrome and not with a webview.

Edit: today (2015-03-19) the pull-down-to-refresh has come to the stable chrome.

Edit: from @Evyn answer I follow [this link](http://jsbin.com/qofuwa/2/quiet) and got this javascript/jquery code that work.

```js
var lastTouchY = 0;
var preventPullToRefresh = false;

$('body').on('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.touches.length != 1) { return; }
    lastTouchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
    preventPullToRefresh = window.pageYOffset == 0;
});

$('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
    var touchY = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
    var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
    lastTouchY = touchY;
    if (preventPullToRefresh) {
        // To suppress pull-to-refresh it is sufficient to preventDefault the first overscrolling touchmove.
        preventPullToRefresh = false;
        if (touchYDelta > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

As @bcintegrity pointed out, I hope for a site manifest solution (and/or a meta-tag) in the future.

Moreover suggestions for the code above are welcome.

Comment: Yeah this really sucks. Was in middle of form and scrolled to top too far and it refreshed and lost everything. This is a retarded default feature, I click the Refresh icon if I want to refresh!

Comment: Would be nice if this feature could be disabled in my web app manifest. Unfortunately, every page on my web app has scrollable content, making it almost impossible to navigate without refreshing. I'm a little ticked. :/

Comment: This is good info. I hate web sites that disable the pull to refresh feature. I'd like to develop a feature to make the refresh work regardless of page content.

Comment: Speaking as a web developer, pulldown refresh is incompatible with data-driven websites, as it reloads the application.  It makes it impossible for a user to scroll to the top of a page without refreshing the whole page.  I am 100% supportive of Chrome, hope they remove this anti-feature.

Comment: Another developer here: if you develop your application smartly, this won't be a problem if you use a datastore like Redux then sync your "consistent" data with localstorage. Data that needs to be refreshed will then update perfectly - and form entries etc will persist, even refresh events.

Comment: I faced myself with this GC "feature"... plenty web pages, many forms, one careless pull down with my finger and data on this page are lost! Retard function IMO. It should be off by default, who need it then let code it. I wondered by days why my "clients" occasionally lost their data on GC...

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/qofuwa/2/quiet does not work for me on Chrome Android

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The default action of the pull-to-refresh effect can be effectively prevented by doing any of the following :

1. `preventDefault`’ing some portion of the touch sequence, including any of the following (in order of most disruptive to least disruptive):

   - a.    The entire touch stream (not ideal).
   - b.    All top overscrolling touchmoves.
   - c.    The first top overscrolling touchmove.
   - d.    The first top overscrolling touchmove only when 1) the initial touchstart occurred when the page y scroll offset was zero and 2) the touchmove would induce top overscroll.
2. Applying “`touch-action: none`” to touch-targeted elements, where appropriate, disabling default actions (including pull-to-refresh) of the touch sequence.
3. Applying “`overflow-y: hidden`” to the body element, using a div for scrollable content if necessary.
4. Disabling the effect locally via `chrome://flags/#disable-pull-to-refresh-effect`).

[See more](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12Ay4s3NWake8Qd6xQeGiYimGJ_gCe0UMDZKwP9Ni4m8/edit)

Comment: Thank you @Evyn . I cannot believe this was a quick fix! I set the CSS for the body element to overflow-y:hidden.

Comment: Thanks @Evyn, I've decided to use the preventDefault() method (first point). In particular I've found interesting the source code of the link ( [link](http://jsbin.com/qofuwa/2/quiet) ) that is inside the document you have linked. I'll put the code at the end of my question.

Comment: how is "chrome://flags (disable-pull-to-refresh-effect)" done programmatically ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere as far as I know, its not impossible. chrome settings can only be set by the user - it would pose a security risk otherwise

Comment: The document that this is based on contains examples where the behaviour should be prevented by the suggestions above, but when testing those jsbin examples on Chrome on Samsung Galaxy Tab A, the refresh effect is not prevented.

Comment: Applying “overflow-y: hidden” to the body element, using a div for scrollable content worked for me.

Comment: Option 3 is just awesome, tried dozens of options and finally the most simple option works, thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks a lot, added touch-action: none in the CSS file at html tag. Problem persists in safari browser

Comment: any idea on how to disable this only for certain page in react?

Answer (score 156):

## Simple solution for 2019+

Chrome 63 has added a css property to help out with exactly this. Have a read through [this guide by Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior) to get a good idea of how you can handle it.

Here is their TL:DR

> The CSS overscroll-behavior property allows developers to override the
>   browser's default overflow scroll behavior when reaching the
>   top/bottom of content. Use cases include disabling the pull-to-refresh
>   feature on mobile, removing overscroll glow and rubberbanding effects,
>   and preventing page content from scrolling when it's beneath a
>   modal/overlay.

To get it working, all you have to add is this in your CSS:

```
body {
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

It is also only [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-overscroll-behavior) by Chrome, Edge and Firefox for now but I'm sure Safari will add it soon as they seem to be fully onboard with service workers and the future of PWA's.

Comment: this is the most up to date anwser

Comment: Has anyone else noticed this delaying the appearance of the "Add to Homescreen" chrome banner?

Comment: had to apply it to the html element in order to disable it

Comment: This work only for Android , Chrome on IOs still to show glows effect + native pull to refresh

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior this link can also explain better

Comment: Gem solution.thnx for help

Answer (score 14):

At the moment you can only disable this feature via [chrome://flags/#disable-pull-to-refresh-effect](http://chrome://flags/#disable-pull-to-refresh-effect) - open directly from your device.

You could try to catch `touchmove` events, but chances are very slim to achieve an acceptable result.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the answer .I could not accept this as the accepted one because I was looking for something not dependent from the users.
However this method works, so I'll upvote your answer as I gain enough reputation.

Comment: It's a pity this seems to be the best solution - what if that flag setting changes in the future, or you want to be able to use pull to refresh on other sites...Surprised that this can't be controlled programmatically. :(.

Comment: If the CEO of Google is reading this, please remove this feature.  It does not seem that it can be easily and comprehensively disabled, and in my opinion is a web application "feature" that not all web applications want.

Answer (score 8):

I use MooTools, and I have created a Class to disable refresh on a targeted element, but the crux of it is (native JS):

```
var target = window; // this can be any scrollable element
var last_y = 0;
target.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    var scrolly = target.pageYOffset || target.scrollTop || 0;
    var direction = e.changedTouches[0].pageY > last_y ? 1 : -1;
    if(direction>0 && scrolly===0){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    last_y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
});
```

All we do here is find the y direction of the touchmove, and if we are moving down the screen and the target scroll is 0, we stop the event. Thus, no refresh.

This means we are firing on every 'move', which can be expensive, but is the best solution I have found so far ...

Comment: It's safe to stop watching as soon as the user scrolls down, as the pull to refresh has no chance of being triggered. Likewise, if `scrolltop > 0`, the event won't be triggered.

In my implementation, I bind the `touchmove` event on `touchstart`, only if `scrollTop <= 0`. I unbind it as soon as the user scrolls down (`initialY >= e.touches[0].clientY`). If the user scrolls up (`previousY < e.touches[0].clientY`), then I call `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 8):

After many hours of trying, this solution works for me

```
$("html").css({
    "touch-action": "pan-down"
});
```

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery for this. Just add the "touch-action: pan-down" to your css code file.

Comment: just use this in your css: `html{touch-action:pan-down}`

Answer (score 8):

You can try this

```
body {
  /* Disables pull-to-refresh but allows overscroll glow effects. */
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

example :

https://ebidel.github.io/demos/chatbox.html

full doc 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior

Comment: The correct answer 

Answer (score 4):

### AngularJS

I have successfully disabled it with this AngularJS directive:

```
//Prevents "pull to reload" behaviour in Chrome. Assign to child scrollable elements.
angular.module('hereApp.directive').directive('noPullToReload', function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var initialY = null,
                previousY = null,
                bindScrollEvent = function(e){
                    previousY = initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;

                    // Pull to reload won't be activated if the element is not initially at scrollTop === 0
                    if(element[0].scrollTop <= 0){
                        element.on("touchmove", blockScroll);
                    }
                },
                blockScroll = function(e){
                    if(previousY && previousY < e.touches[0].clientY){ //Scrolling up
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    else if(initialY >= e.touches[0].clientY){ //Scrolling down
                        //As soon as you scroll down, there is no risk of pulling to reload
                        element.off("touchmove", blockScroll);
                    }
                    previousY = e.touches[0].clientY;
                },
                unbindScrollEvent = function(e){
                    element.off("touchmove", blockScroll);
                };
            element.on("touchstart", bindScrollEvent);
            element.on("touchend", unbindScrollEvent);
        }
    };
});
```

It's safe to stop watching as soon as the user scrolls down, as the pull to refresh has no chance of being triggered.

Likewise, if `scrolltop > 0`, the event won't be triggered. In my implementation, I bind the touchmove event on touchstart, only if `scrollTop <= 0`. I unbind it as soon as the user scrolls down (`initialY >= e.touches[0].clientY`). If the user scrolls up (`previousY < e.touches[0].clientY`), then I call `preventDefault()`.

This saves us from watching scroll events needlessly, yet blocks overscrolling.

### jQuery

If you are using jQuery, this is the **untested** equivalent. `element` is a jQuery element:

```
var initialY = null,
    previousY = null,
    bindScrollEvent = function(e){
        previousY = initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;

        // Pull to reload won't be activated if the element is not initially at scrollTop === 0
        if(element[0].scrollTop <= 0){
            element.on("touchmove", blockScroll);
        }
    },
    blockScroll = function(e){
        if(previousY && previousY < e.touches[0].clientY){ //Scrolling up
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(initialY >= e.touches[0].clientY){ //Scrolling down
            //As soon as you scroll down, there is no risk of pulling to reload
            element.off("touchmove");
        }
        previousY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    },
    unbindScrollEvent = function(e){
        element.off("touchmove");
    };
element.on("touchstart", bindScrollEvent);
element.on("touchend", unbindScrollEvent);
```

Naturally, the same can also be achieved with pure JS.

Comment: I had to use `e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY` to make this work. Still struggling with the logic *when* to prevent reload. Right now it seems to randomly prevent scrolling up ... Put thanks for the hint in the right direction!

Comment: What element is the directive added to?

Comment: The AngularJS directive worked well for me. We are using Framework7 and Angular together (wouldn't suggest it) and something was blocking the correct behaviour of scrollTop. So I had to modify when the blockScroll would be added to the element. But just wanted to say thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Simple Javascript

I implemented using standard javascript. Simple and easy to implement. Just paste and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">         //<![CDATA[
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          var maybePreventPullToRefresh = false;
          var lastTouchY = 0;
          var touchstartHandler = function(e) {
            if (e.touches.length != 1) return;
            lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
            // Pull-to-refresh will only trigger if the scroll begins when the
            // document's Y offset is zero.
            maybePreventPullToRefresh =
                window.pageYOffset == 0;
          }

          var touchmoveHandler = function(e) {
            var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
            var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
            lastTouchY = touchY;

            if (maybePreventPullToRefresh) {
              // To suppress pull-to-refresh it is sufficient to preventDefault the
              // first overscrolling touchmove.
              maybePreventPullToRefresh = false;
              if (touchYDelta > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
              }
            }
          }

          document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, false);
          document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, false);      });
            //]]>    </script>
```

Comment: This worked very well for Chrome, but caused some issues with scrolling up for me on Safari/iOS 9.2 when scrolling a div at the top of the page (reproduced [here](https://jsbin.com/tiranas/189/edit?css,js)).  I ended up using the `body: {overflow-y:hidden}` trick from [Evyn above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29313685/614523).

Comment: downvoting as does not works on chrome , but works in firefox example , https://embed.plnkr.co/rqbOVSOkKyhAgoHK2sEP/    open in MOBILE ONLY

Comment: the link that you pasted did work in chrome as well on my android mobile. it did not allow to refresh on pull. which version of android/ios are you using to test?

Comment: From Chrome 56 you need to set passive: false to make it work:

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, { passive: false });
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, { passive: false });

Answer (score 4):

The best solution on pure CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#pseudobody {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

See this demo: https://jsbin.com/pokusideha/quiet

Comment: do you really tested this on a mobile using chrome?

Answer (score 3):

I find setting your **body** CSS **overflow-y:hidden** is the simplest way. If you did want to have a scrolling application page you can just use a div container with scrolling features.

Comment: Seems impossible to fix it with a line but works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Note that overflow-y is not inherited, so you need to set it on ALL block elements.

You can do this with jQuery simply by:

```
        $(document.body).css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); 
        $('*').filter(function(index) {
            return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
        }).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Among the other answers, this one really helps. Thanks. 

Add this line into css. 

body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

Answer (score 2):

Since a couple of weeks I found out that the javascript function that I used to disable the Chrome refresh action won't work anymore. I have made this to solve it:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 1) {
      $("html").css({
         "touch-action": "auto"}
      );
   } else {
      $("html").css({
         "touch-action": "pan-down"
      });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure js solution.

```
// Prevent pull refresh chrome
    var lastTouchY = 0;
    var preventPullToRefresh = false;
    window.document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
        if (e.touches.length != 1) { return; }
        lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        preventPullToRefresh = window.pageYOffset == 0;
    }, false);

    window.document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){

        var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
        var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
        lastTouchY = touchY;
        if (preventPullToRefresh) {
            // To suppress pull-to-refresh it is sufficient to preventDefault the first overscrolling touchmove.
            preventPullToRefresh = false;
            if (touchYDelta > 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        }

    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the pull-down-to-refresh problem with this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add following to the `touchstart` and `touchend`/`touchcancel` events:

```
scrollTo(0, 1)
```

Since chrome does not scroll if it's not on scrollY position `0` this will prevent chrome from doing pull to refresh.

If it still does not work, try also doing that when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
html {
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did using nextjs/react

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    function preventPullToRefresh() {
     var lastTouchY = 0;
     document.addEventListener(
      "touchstart",
      function (e) {
       if (e.touches.length !== 1) return;
       lastTouchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
      },
      {passive: false}
     );

     document.addEventListener(
      "touchmove",
      function (e) {
       var touchY = e.touches[0].clientY;
       var touchYDelta = touchY - lastTouchY;
       lastTouchY = touchY;
       if (touchYDelta > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
       }
      },
      {passive: false}
     );
    }

    preventPullToRefresh();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple and recommended solution in 2023, as per the recommendations by [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/overscroll-behavior/) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior), which works both in both mobile browsers:

```
HTML {
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}
BODY {
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```