# Page refreshes on input form field Touch Events - Android, Samsung

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, touch

Hey guys I am trying to trouble shoot an issue that seems to be only happening on certain Android devices that are version 5 or older.

What happens is, when I touch an input field say email-address or password to login, the page refreshes which makes it impossible to ever enter any information.

This is not just limited to those fields, but any form fields in the application.  We have a leave feedback page and that form field also refreshes the page.

I had assumed I was having the same issue as [Disabling android's chrome pull-down-to-refresh feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature) 
But none of those solutions seem to be working for me and I just can't figure out what exactly is happening.

The information on my Android device:

Samsung Galaxy Tab A
Version 5.0.2
Is happening on Firefox, and Chrome on the device.

I am a little new to debugging on Android and could not find the version of touch my device is using.

We are using Jquery mobile for the front-end and some bootstrap javascript/css for forms.

Comment: I've noticed something similar on Windows touch screen devices in Chrome where when changing a select box is randomly clicking menu items at the same time. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @iamjonesy I just answered it with what was happening on our side.  I don't think this will help you though, good luck to you.  Weird bugs though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I found out, was that whenever the screen resizes we do a refresh event for the new screen size.

What was happening on Android is that we had a css property `

> orientation: landscape

on landscape mode.  Well what was happening is you would click the form field on Android the keyboard fires and resizes the screen.  Which was triggering a refresh, which took the keyboard away and sized the screen back to the regular screen with no keyboard event.

How we fixed this was using:

> min-aspect-ratio: 13/9

This however was not happening on iOS because as far as I can tell, iOS just triggers a scroll-bar event instead of a screen resize event when the keyboard opens.