# mobile: how to prevent pull-to-refresh

Tags: google-chrome, pull-to-refresh

How to prevent pull-to-refresh in web applications for Chrome android?

I tried the answers from

[Disabling android's chrome pull-down-to-refresh feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature)

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

or

```
body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

It did not work. any one has a solution that works? It is very bad for browsers to make pull-to-refresh default behavior, it is very undesirable for web applications.

Comment: It would be really good if there was a robust solution to this that wasn't likely to change with the next chrome update etc.

Comment: Pretty interesting.  Maybe I'll take a swing at it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS method of capturing the required touch gestures to prevent the pull to refresh:

```
$("html").css({
    "touch-action": "pan-down"
});
```

This method seems to have worked well for other users.  Hope it works for your needs.

Reference, plus there's more strategies discussed here:
[Disabling android's chrome pull-down-to-refresh feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
html,body{overscroll-behavior:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a javascript-only solution distilled from a couple of sources, which are towards the bottom.

If you are willing to change the structure of your pages, a CSS/HTML only option may work for you.

Additionally, the draft CSS property `scroll-boundary-behavior` is in the process of being standardized and added to Chrome provide this capability among a few others.  As the implementation is very, very new, I provide links at the bottom of my answer.

## [Example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ca9mar2L/11/show/light/)

although jsfiddle's iframe structure prevents pull-to-refresh from working at all, I also tested the same script within a flat HTML document on Chrome Android 60.0.3112.116.

[Full jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca9mar2L/11/)

`event.preventDefault()` can keep browser default behaviors such as pull-to-refresh from taking place.  We want the usual browser behavior most of the time, just not when it would lead to a pull-to-refresh.  Since a pull-to-refresh happens when touches are moving down the screen and we're scrolled to the top of the document, we'll only call `preventDefault` under those conditions.

```
//We're going to make a closure that will handle events
//so as to prevent the pull-to-refresh behavior.
var pullToRefreshPreventer = (function() {
  //To determine the direction in which a touch is moving,
  //we hold on to a map from touch identifier to touches
  //from the previous event.
  var previousTouches = {};
  return function(event) {
    //First we get all touches in this event and set up
    //the value which will replace `previousTouches`
    //before this event handler exits.
    var touches = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.touches);
    nextTouches = {}
    touches.forEach(function(touch){
      nextTouches[touch.identifier] = touch;
    });

    //Pull-to-refresh behavior only happens if we are
    //scrolled to the top of the document, so we can
    //exit early if we are somewhere in the middle.
    if(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      previousTouches = nextTouches;
      return;
    }

    //Now we know that we are scrolled to the top of
    //the document;
    //look through the current set of touches and see
    //if any of them have moved down the page.
    for(var ix = 0; ix < touches.length; ix++) {
      var touch = touches[ix],
          id = touch.identifier;
      //If this touch was captured in a previous event
      //and it has moved downwards, we call preventDefault
      //to prevent the pull-to-refresh behavior.
      if(id in previousTouches && previousTouches[id].screenY < touch.screenY) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("event.preventDefault() called")
        break;
      }
    }
    //lastly, we update previousTouches
    previousTouches = nextTouches;
  };
}());

//Since touch events which may call `preventDefault` can be
//much more expensive to handle, Chrome disallows such calls
//by default.  We must add the options argument `{passive: false}`
//here to make it work.
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', pullToRefreshPreventer, {passive: false});
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', pullToRefreshPreventer, {passive: false});
```

References:

[StackOverflow answer linking to chromestatus.com page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42509310/revisions)

["Treat Document Level Touch Event Listeners as Passive", chromestatus](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080)

["Making touch scrolling fast by default"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention)

["Touch events"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

`scroll-boundary-behavior` links:

[chromestatus](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5734614437986304)

[chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=672921)

[github issue proposing the standard](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/769)

[draft css module](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-boundary-behavior/), last publish date 2017-09-07

Comment: I haven't been able to test on tablet yet, but will accept as answer as I don't want you to miss out on bounty if it expires!  Hope it works and will test and confirm asap!  Thank you.

Comment: LMK how it goes!

Comment: Results:  Remote debugging on PC, when using mouse to simulate swipe down, see orange information message in Chrome developer tools `Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted`.  1)  On PC debugging screen, I **can** make page refresh using mouse to swipe down.  2)  I **cannot** make page refresh using finger and swipe down on tablet.  3)  However, I **can** make page refresh if I swipe down on a jqueryu ui autocomplete dropdown when it is at the top of its list.  Because of 3, not successful yet.

Comment: PS This is how I am remote debugging from Android to PC https://stackoverflow.com/q/45560325

Comment: Chrome version?

Comment: `Chrome 60.0.3112.116` on `Android 7.0.0; SM-P585Y Build/NRD90M`

Comment: Also, the jsfiddle does not exhibit pull to refresh behaviour with or without the JS code unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I noted that above-- "although jsfiddle's iframe structure prevents pull-to-refresh from working at all" -- the jsfiddle structures its pages so that there's always a DOM wrapper that prevents pull-to-refresh.  If you go and try to directly visit the URL which it uses for the result iframe, it also throws it in a wrapper.

Comment: You can repro this if you take it off of jsfiddle.  I just did the following: 1. on a desktop machine w/ chrome, clear browser cache; 2. visit https://jsfiddle.net/ca9mar2L/11/; 3. in the same browser tab, visit https://fiddle.jshell.net/ca9mar2L/11/show/; observe NO jsfiddle wrapper dom present; 4. download html file; email to myself, open in mobile chrome; observe pull-to-refresh does not work; 4. remove script tag containing example code; email to myself again; open in mobile chrome; observe pull-to-refresh works

Comment: Or, to avoid any chance of jsfiddle messing things up by adding a DOM wrapper, just copy this stuff to an html file that you directly control.

Comment: Sorry about that oversight re: jsfiddle environment.  Thanks for detailed testing instructions.  Results are still as described above however (the orange information message in console and jqueryui autocomplete swiping causes page refresh).