# Cache Manifest loses page after "Refresh Page"

Tags: c#, html, cache-manifest

We have a cache manifest in our MVC C# application. At the moment its caching `.js` `.css` and some `HTML` files.

This works great initially, but on returning to the Index page - and triggering a Refresh in `Safari` whilst offline, the browser will show an offline screen.

We wish for this application to be available offline if cached, even if a refresh is triggered. We would also like to allow the page to be available when a user enters the browser and types the URL in the address bar **whilst offline**.

Here is our manifest page:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version 1

CACHE:
~/
~/Content/style.css
~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js
~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
~/events.html
~/index.html

FALLBACK:
/events /events.html


NETWORK:
*

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Please assist us by letting us know if:

1. This is possible?
2. What needs to change in our configuration/manifest.
3. Alternative methods/resources to look at.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't much of a fix but I'll post it as a possible solution incase someone lands on this page.

So basically we disabled `'pull down to refresh'` and preloaded our pages on the index page. Using jquery mobile to change page between them. (as JQuery mobile basically treats this as a single page application after that.)

**We disabled refresh by doing this:**

`chrome://flags/#disable-pull-to-refresh-effect`
documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171474/1800668

**preloading pages:**

```
<div style="display:none;">
        <a href="/Rou/Rou" data-prefetch>Prefeched</a>
        <a href="/Li/RoLif" data-prefetch>Prefeched</a>
        <a href="/Li/Sint" data-prefetch>Prefeched</a>
        <a href="/Sig/Signature" data-prefetch>Prefeched</a>
        <a href="/Home/Logout" data-prefetch>Prefeched</a>
    </div>
```