# Is it possible to measure the distance of the overflow scroll?

Tags: javascript

The title refers to the scroll inertia found in most browsers when you scroll out of the document bounds.

I would like to calculate span of the inertia, as in the max distance? More specifically, when the user scrolls to the top of page.

If this is not possible, is it possible to just register a count of when this event happens? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is a feature of browsers themselves.  My advice would be to just create a constant which represents this amount instead of trying to query some variable which stores it. So you'll have to build some map saying Chrome = 50, Safari = 75 or whatever they are.

I havent tried it in years but I believe the `onScroll` events will go in to negative `y` when you're causing this effect to happen.

And in case you trying to do something to negate this effect, it's possible to turn it off entirely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008194/disabling-androids-chrome-pull-down-to-refresh-feature

Comment: Chrome doesn't have this on Windows 10 as far as I can tell.